# Is $ f(x,y) $ continuous function?

Tags: analysis

There is a given function f(x,y): $ (1-\cos \frac{x^2}{y}) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ when $ y \neq 0$ and $0$ when $y=0$.

I have to test if it's continuous. How should I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Check if $$\lim_{y\to0}f(x,y) $$ exists and is equal to $0$.

Comment: "How should I do it?" For any point with $y\neq0$ there is clearly no problem. It remains to show that small values of $y$ gives small values of $f$ (preferably with something like $\epsilon$-$\delta$).

Comment: Choose $\delta > 0$ and let $y<\delta$. Note that if $f$ were continuous, $|f(x,y)| < \epsilon$ for any $x$. Is this true?

Comment: It might also be helpful to notice that $$ \left\vert 1 - \cos \frac{x^2}{y} \right\vert \leq 1 + \left\vert \cos \frac{x^2}{y} \right\vert \leq 1+1=2 $$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R},\; y\not=0$.

Comment: @stakindmidl  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

We need to check whether or not for any $x$

$$\lim_{y\to 0} \, \left(1-\cos \left(\frac{x^2}{y}\right)\right) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=0$$

which is true if and only if $x=0$.

Indeed for $x=0$ and $y\neq 0$ we have $f(x,y)=0$ but for $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$ let assume

- $y_n=\frac{x^2}{(2n+1)\pi}\to 0$

we have that

$$1-\cos \left(\frac{x^2}{y}\right)=1-\cos ((2n+1)\pi)=2$$

Therefore $f(x,y)$ is continuos at $(0,0)$ but is not continuous for any other point along the $x$ axis.

Comment: My reading of this function is that $f(100, 0)=0$, which causes problems for your proof.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Yes of course! I was considering the case $x=0$. I've fixed that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In general, proving the continuity of functions like this one is rather straightforward. Each piece of the piecewise definition is continuous on the region it is defined on, so the only way this function could be discontinuous is when it “switches” from one function to the other.

In your case, the only potential issue is at $y=0$. So, to prove continuity it is sufficient to prove continuity at $y=0$. This function is continuous at $y=0$ if and only if

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\left(1-\cos \frac{x^2}{y}\right) \sqrt{x^2+y^2} =0$$

holds for every $x$. To get started on this, try plugging in $x=100$ and see what happens when you take the limit.

Answer (score 0):

If we were to have that $f$ were continuous, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there would exist some $\delta > 0$ such that $y <\delta$ implies that $|f(x,y)| < \epsilon$. If such a $\delta$ exists, take $y<\delta$ and let $x = \sqrt{\frac{(2k+1)\pi y}{2}}$. This choice of $x$ is motivated by the fact that (through a straightforward computation), \begin{align*}
\cos\left(\frac{x^2}{y}\right) = 0
 \end{align*}
Thus, $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Given our value of $x$, why does this contradict continuity?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, you helped a lot!

I want to check this answer with you. My first attempt was something like this:

I used the two cops theorem.
since $0\leq|\cos \frac{x^2}{y} |\leq1$, there is $|1- \cos \frac{x^2}{y}| \leq 1$, I got this:

$$0 \leq |(1- \cos \frac{x^2}{y}) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}| \leq |1-\cos \frac{x^2}{y}||\sqrt{x^2+y^2}| \leq |\sqrt{x^2+y^2}|$$

While $y \rightarrow 0$, we get $\leq |\sqrt{x^2}|$ and this is equal to zero only and only if $x=0$. For any other $x$ different than $0$, $f$ is not continuous.

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: When $x\neq 0$ we need to show that the limit is not $0$ and for that, since the square root part is equal to $|x|$, it suffices to show that $(1- \cos \frac{x^2}{y})\not \to 0$. For this latter part it is intuitive that since $x\neq 0$ when $y\to 0$ the expression oscillates between $0$ and $2$ therefore the limit doesn't exists. For a rigorous proof the best way is to explicitely show some path for which the limit is not $0$ as for example $y_n=\frac{x^2}{(2n+1)\pi}\to 0$.

Comment: Note also that there exist paths for which the limit is equal to 0 also for $x\neq 0$, as for example $y_n=\frac{x^2}{2n\pi}\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Take some arbitrary point on $(x_0,0)$, $ x_0 \neq 0$. If you take the limit $ y\to 0$ clearly the "second" part of the function, i.e., $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ does not have any problem approaching $(1,0)$ (in whatever path you choose). So take a look at the "first" part that has $ \cos(x^2/y)$, if $ x=x_0$ then you have $ \cos(x_0^2/y)$. You should be familiar with the (univariate) definition of limit according to Heine. So try to choose two sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ (hint: $\cos(x)$ is periodic function) that converge to $0$, while $\cos( x_0^2/y)$ goes to two different values. For the $(0,0)$ point, just note that $\cos(x^2/y)$ is bounded function, while $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 }$ goes to zero.